# Calculate active time of an employee

Tags: node.js, mongodb, algorithm

I am trying to create a timesheet for employees where I am saving each event(Active, Inactive) as a timestamp in MongoDB. How to calculate the active time of an employee from a given time?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8c8dcca4c6010e29140e0e"), 
    "activityAt" : ISODate("2019-09-26T10:07:05.388+0000"), 
    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
    "deleted_at" : null, 
    "event" : "ACTIVE", 
    "employeeId" : ObjectId("5d78fba602c9265fc7ad6273"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-09-26T10:07:08.479+0000"), 
    "modified_at" : ISODate("2019-09-26T10:07:08.479+0000")
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8c8dcca4c6010e29140e0f"), 
    "activityAt" : ISODate("2019-09-26T11:07:05.388+0000"), 
    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
    "deleted_at" : null, 
    "event" : "INACTIVE", 
    "employeeId" : ObjectId("5d78fba602c9265fc7ad6273"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-09-26T11:07:08.481+0000"), 
    "modified_at" : ISODate("2019-09-26T11:07:08.481+0000")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For every entry that is 'active', take the date from ISODate and subtract from it the current date (or any given time). The result will be all the active time the employee has.

In pseudocode:

```
active_time = 0
for entry in db:
    if entry.event == 'ACTIVE':
        active_time = active_time + (current_date - entry.ISODate)
return active_time
```

The only thing you would need to do is convert the date into something that can be subtracted/added/etc. A solution would be to convert it to hours.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in this case, there will be a timestamp of inactive as well. For example, an employee is active at 11:00 AM and gets inactive at 12:00 PM and then again gets active on 15:00 PM and continues active inactive session. Then how can I calculate the sum of active time which in the case of 11:00 to 12:00 PM is 1 hour and + after 15:00 PM till he becomes inactive?

Comment: In my answer only active time is calculated. My algorithm does not count inactive time. So it will only take into account the time in which the employee is active. No further calculation is needed.